# How to send messages to multiple users using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am using PHP Messaging system to send messages between user's. But my question was, how to send messages to multiple user's in new_pm.php.

http://www.webestools.com/scripts_tutorials-code-source-15-personal-message-system-in-php-mysql-pm-system-private-message-discussion.html

```
$dn1 = mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query('select count(id) as recip, id as 
recipid, (select count(*) from pm) as npm from registrationform where 
email="'.$recip.'" '));

if($conn->query('insert into pm (id, id2, title, user1, user2, message, 
timestamp, user1read, user2read)values("'.$id.'", "1", "'.$title.'", 
"'.$id1.'", "'.$dn1['recipid'].'", "'.$message.'", "'.time().'", "yes", 
"no")'))
```

Comment: loop through email

Comment: you are inserting into database. so insert message data for each user2 by looping through all the user2's and changing the $dn1['recipid'] accordingly.

Comment: @turtle tread can i have an example to understand.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudocode:

foreach user2array as user
do your insert query but for user2 column, replace the value with the recipient user id.

What is the id2 column I'm not sure. Maybe you can figure out.

Comment: nice downvote cuz you too lazy to figure anything out for yourself. Good luck in coding.